# generate oracle database using persistence file hibernate

Tags: eclipse, oracle, hibernate

My work space have some projects depends on each others , one of them contains entities classes , persistence.xml and orm.xml. 
I want to remove any useless columns from my oracle db which doesn't exist in these entities. 
but I know that I can generate another database from these entities and it will be easier specially I have 166 entity. 
So how can I generate a new database using this entity project
My environment is :
webSphere Application server v8.5 , oracle db 11g and Eclipse KEPLER .

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere Application Server v85 is Java EE 6 compliant, but if you upgrade to a Java EE 7 compliant version (e.g. WAS v9 or WAS Liberty 8556+) the ability to auto create tables from entities is there.

To auto create tables, put this property in your persistence.xml:

```
<persistence ...>

  <persistence-unit name="test">
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
                value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Possible values for this property are:

> none, create, drop-and-create, drop

For more info see this article on JPA 2.1 standard properties:
[Standardized schema generation and data loading with JPA 2.1](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/standardized-schema-generation-data-loading-jpa-2-1/)